# Unity3D, multiple audio sources on one object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to add multiple audio sources (gun shoot, reload) on my gun.

I don't know how to achive this.

Answer (score 5):

You are free to add multiple components of the same type on the same gameobject.

The "difficuly", is to retrieve the correct audioSource.

Supposing you have the following script attached to a gameObject:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GunSound : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource ShootAudioSource;
    public AudioSource ReloadAudioSource;

    public void PlayShootSound()
    {
        ShootAudioSource.Play();
    }
    public void PlayReloadSound()
    {
        ReloadAudioSource.Play();
    }
}
```

Then, in your inspector, you will have two AudioSource fields.

Drag & Drop both audio sources by following these steps:

1. Select the object holding your script
2. Lock the inspector using the little lock at the top right of the inspector
3. Open a new Inspector tab (Right click on the first Inspector tab > Add tab > Inspector), and move it so that you can see both Inspector tabs
4. Select the gameObject with the multiple AudioSources. The 1st Inspector tab should not change (thanks to the little lock), but the second one should show the components of your newly selected object
5. With your mouse, click and hold the left button on the text `AudioSource` of the first AudioSource component. Then, drop the selection in the field in the 1st Inspector tab
6. Do the same for the second AudioSource

[image]

Comment: Does this work the same for animations? I have a animation when you fire and when you reload.

Comment: I guess it works too!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try it later and let you know

Comment: It says when i start the game: "Cannot play an disabled audio source", but it is not disabled

Comment: Are you sure the gameobject nor the component are disabled? Are you sure you have referenced the correct audio source ?

Comment: None of it is disabled and i did exact what you said.

Comment: Well, I don't know what's happening, but it is clearly not related to the script. Try to Google the error, you may find where the problem comes from.

Comment: i did exact the same, but only the first audio is playing, the rest, even if i called play() method, still won't play, i checked the volume and everything, i just can't hear it